# server tag is not well formed in repeater data source control in asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, repeater

i want to show a image in a repeater , image source is database. and datatype is varbinary(max). While adding image tag getting error saying -

> "The server tag is not well formed."

how to add image in a data as well as image in a repeater control.

code

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="RepterDetails" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <HeaderTemplate>
    <table style="border:1px solid #0000FF; width:500px" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
    <b>Testimonial</b>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
    <tr style="background-color:#EBEFF0">
    <td>
    <table >
    <tr>
    <td >
    Comments:
    <asp:Label ID="lblSubject" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("comment") %>'/>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <asp:Label ID="lblComment" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("designation") %>'/>
    </td>
    </tr>
   </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Image ID="Image1" Height="100px" Width="100px" runat="server" ImageUrl="<%# "data:Image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("organizationLogo")) %>"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
    </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: try change `ImageUrl="<%#` to single quote so `ImageUrl='<%#` and same for the attributes closing quote

Comment: thanks. its working now

Comment: I'll add as answer then - please accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either escape your double quotes or use a single quote for `ImageUrl` attribute.

so this

```
ImageUrl="<%# "data:Image/png;base64,"+Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("organizationLogo")) %>"
```

becomes this...

```
ImageUrl='<%# "data:Image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("organizationLogo")) %>'
```